# how to modify the host window from a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

i'm coding a c# application using WPF

i have a main Window which contain a Grid named " SelectionGrid ". this grid will contain Control User, my problem is that i want to modify ( add/delete) Control User in that grid from a USER CONTROL itself

for example: 
SelectionGrid host the User Control " Menu" in this menu there a button, i want from this button to remove the Menu User Control and add another User Control in this SelectionGrid

main window code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserControl usc = new Menu();
        SelectionGrid.Children.Add(usc);
    }}
```

Menu User Control code :

```
public partial class Menu : UserControl
{
    public Menu()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // want to add Another User Control in SelectionGrid
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,put your userControl in some container control like `Grid`.Then you can easily access and modify the grid from the usercontrol as follows:

```
 var parent = (Grid)this.Parent;
 ///do what you want to do with parent
```

**A bit of knowledge-sharing** : The below code can be used to access the parent of controls like `Page`,`UserControl` :

```
public static T FindParent(DependencyObject child)
{
DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
if (parentObject == null)
    return null;
T parent = parentObject as T;
if (parent != null)
    return parent;
else
    return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
}

private void test()
{
  ControlTypeHere parent = FindParent<ControlTypeHere>(this);
```

Hope this helps :)